# FULL JOIN in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to display a list of "last entries" in a budget app. The entries (like expenses, income, account transfers, loans) have different columns defined apart from a user_id.

In SQL I would go for a FULL JOIN, but I am using SQLAlchemy (declarative). What is the correct approach here? Some meta table?

Thanks a lot.

Example tables:

```
class Expense(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'expenses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    date = Column(Integer)
    category = Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('expense_categories.id'))
    description = Column(String(50))
    deduct_from = Column('account_id', Integer, ForeignKey('accounts.id'))
    amount = Column(Float(precision=2))

class Loan(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'loans'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    from_user = Column('from_user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    to_user = Column('to_user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    date = Column(Integer)
    account = Column('account_id', Integer, ForeignKey('accounts.id'))
    description = Column(String(50))
    amount = Column(Float(precision=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use [raw SQL](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_statement) if your database supports it or an [union](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.union) otherewise. from http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/msg/80ea8e712380bff4

Comment: I used this to build a full join statement http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_6/core/compiler.html